# activity sending data even if user has exited it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, runnable

I want in my app to do the following. I wan even if the user press the home key my app will still continue to send data (indefinitely until the app is killed). In pseudocode I want something like this:

```
even_if_i_have_pressed_home_button {
    for (;;) sendData();
}
```

Can you help me in what to use? I have read about services, threads or runnables. Can you suggest me something and give me example code?

Comment: So you suggest using a service?

Comment: you create a service.... read about creating a service.

Comment: Please use `android-activity` instead of `activity`, and `android-service` instead of `service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will create a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), and the service will create a thread that will run continuously. service implementation is a large topic and cannot be covered here. start by reading the android [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) documentation page. here are some things to keep in mind,

1. if you are going to create a thread that runs and continues to perform work after the application user interface has stopped, make sure that you add a [notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) so the user understands this, and provide them with a way to really stop the service. for example, clicking on the notification will bring them back to the application's user interface with a way to "exit".
2. android will destroy your service if it needs the memory. you cannot create a service that will absolutely continue to run. you should consider this in your application design.
3. make sure you really need to do this. having on-going network activity will have severe impact on the user's battery life. consider letting the phone go to sleep and waking up periodically to perform work using [alarm manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service for that, services only get killed by Android in "emergency" cases, so it will most likely remain active when your app's activity closes.
Be sure to handle a close of your service as well, you could use the service's onDestroy method for that.